# Session Expiration Handling in Apache Click (Clickide-2.3.0.)

Tags: apache, session, click-framework

I am a newbie  to Apache Click Framework and I have been evaluating Clickide-2.3.0.0 over the past few days. I am stuck on one part involving session timeouts.

If I want to handle session expiry by setting session timeout interval in my server configuration (I am using Apache Tomcat 7), there is no support provided by Click as provided in case of other Frameworks like ZK (timeout-uri specified in .zul file)

All the work-arounds that I have found so far involve hard coding the validation and constraint checks explicitly in Java using session objects or context manipulation. No support available from Framework side.

Answer (score 0):

It Page or Control has a [Context](https://click.apache.org/docs/click-api/org/apache/click/Context.html) object. The Apache Click docs has some [examples](https://click.apache.org/docs/user-guide/html/ch02s04.html) about it.